# Using Codable Protocol or external Tool for JSON mapping

Tags: json, swift, database, firebase, mapping

I'm using an HTTP cloud function which returns a JSONObject instead of snapshot values. In projects before I've used libraries for this like:

- https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper

or

- https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

But I just noticed swift 4.1 now has a standard library for this named Codable Protocol which should be way more customizable than the external tools.

Which would you guys recommend and why?

(Using a nonSQL database model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `Codable` is a `typealias` not `protocol` ,

```
/// `Codable` is a type alias for the `Encodable` and `Decodable` protocols.
/// When you use `Codable` as a type or a generic constraint, it matches
/// any type that conforms to both protocols.
public typealias Codable = Decodable & Encodable
```

This is a self preference question, but however i will talk about why `Codable`, 
for me the less there are dependencies the better.

`Codable` is strong yet still limited to some points,

> Codable eliminates the need for any initializing function, given that we are content with our object’s properties having the same name as their JSON keys, and can assume that the JSON data is in the same format we expect the Object’s properties to be in (i.e. strings properly capitalized, URLs with or without schemes).

I suggest for you to understand `Codable` first then you can simply decide what you want to use, i recommend this [article](https://possiblemobile.com/2018/04/swift-codable-protocol-part-i/) pretty much what you need for this case

Comment: Thank you! I've worked with NSObject and NSCoding before would that be similar?

Comment: Not really, there are no Next Step classes involved in this, check out the article i promise it would help you

Comment: Thank you I will certainly do that!

Answer (score 2):

This question is a difficult one to answer for a few reasons mainly because it comes down to personal preference and what is the best tool for the job you are doing.

I used to be a big fan of SwiftyJSON, but after Codeable came out, I made the switch mainly because it was one less dependency for my projects. Swift keeps it up to date and working with latest features. With a third-party framework, you have to wait for them to be updated by the owners.

However, I still use Alamofire over Swift's native networking framework because I would still have to build a wrapper around the Swift version and maintain that. Alamofire takes care of this for me; however this is not the case with Codeable, I have never needed to build my own wrapper around it.

Personally, I would go with Codeable it's fast and reliable, but that is my personal choice.

Answer (score 1):

## Intro

Originally I was big fan of `ObjectMapper` and used it in every project. But lately I got in team that try to use third-party dependencies at minimum and you know what? I don't see any difference. (even before Codable come out)

Working with JSON splits on 2 tasks: Encode and Decode:

## Encoding

Encoding is easy and straight forward. You just need to write method that convert your object in dictionary. Done. Do you need third party here? I don't thinks so.

## Decoding

Decoding basically is initiating your object from dictionary. And here third parties could help by making work with json smaller and more expressive.

Or you can cheat here and make shortcut:

```swift
extension Dictionary {
    func get<T>(_ key: Key) -> T? {
        return self[key] as? T
    }
}
Person(
    name: dict.get("name")
)
```

## Conclusion

Looks like third parties wins? I not sure. In most projects time you spend working with JSON is so small compared to working on business logic, UI, animations, testing, code review, etc.

Now you need to ask yourself, is saving half hour and hundred lines of code worth introducing new dependency? Are you sure next person who will work on this project will know this tool (he definitely will know basic swift)? How long you will wait for framework update with new swift version (not so valid anymore)?

For my self I decide that it not worth it. Your call.